# User profile edited by moderators - some questions

Tags: support, profile-page, images

I recently got information from the moderators that my profile on Stack Overflow was edited by them and the photo of a father crying over his son's body in Mariupol was removed from it.

That photo was published in, among others, The Guardian - [here](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/mar/03/father-mourns-son-as-civilian-victims-of-ukraine-crisis-continue-to-mount).

1. Why can The Guardian publish a photo like this, but I can't?
2. Until now, I thought that the profile was personal and could not be censored by someone else (unless it broke the law). Has something changed?
3. Are there rules governing what can and cannot be on a profile?

So far I haven't recived an explanation from moderators - only such (personal?) opinions as below:

> (...) a picture of a father weeping over a bloody sheet concealing a corpse is a bit much.

> (...) but we do have to draw the line at showing a corpse.

Comment: I'm not taking a stance on the validity of the removal because I haven't looked at any of it, but 1. because the Guardian is a different website. They decide where they draw the line, SO decides where it draws the line. That line doesn't have to be identical, and where either of the two draw the line has no effect on the other. 2. With exceptions, yes, because: 3. yes, there are rules, but the rules are laxer compared to content elsewhere on the site. For instance, profiles can be political (ref. mine, for one), or contain promotional content, but there are still limits.

Comment: If you, for instance, include porn on your profile, that'll get you in trouble. Porn isn't illegal (... at least in the US where the site is based. There are countries where it is illegal, but they're irrelevant for this example and the rules of the site), but showing it on this site in particular happens to be against the rules of the site. PornHub has tons of porn, but that still doesn't justify it here. Again, different sites draw different lines, and those lines don't affect the other.

Comment: Why do you consider the statement, *"...we do have to draw the line at showing a corpse."* to be an opinion instead of an explanation?

Comment: @BSMP this statement not explain reason. It's the same like you say to kid "do not drink tea" - but you not explain reason him why drinking tea is bad idea. But maybe I'm not uderstand this statement right due to my level of english

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski:  I think that *is* the reason.  Showing a corpse - even in your profile picture - is A Bit Much™ for a site like Stack Overflow.  We don't come to a site like this to click on someone's profile to be greeted with that kind of imagery.  What further justification would satisfy you here?

Comment: *That photo was published in, among others, The Guardian* That photo is not from the Guardian, it's from Evegeniy Maloletka, and it's licensed through the [Associated Press](http://www.apimages.com/metadata/Index/APTOPIX-Russia-Ukraine-War/525b3917faee4555b582f63d58ec02cf/313/0), and that license only allows for editorial works. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you didn't get an individualized license to use it in a profile picture.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was the moderator who removed it. I discussed it with some other moderators before doing so. My apologies if what I sent you wasn't clear.

The problem there is what we call **graphic content**. A good synonym there is explicit (where the action or result isn't merely implied, but shown, often in detail). In the US in particular, we filter graphic things, or at least warn users before showing them something graphic (i.e. "This report features images that may be disturbing to some viewers").

The problem was that you have a man weeping over a bloody sheet, where there's clearly a dead body beneath. The tragedies of this terrible war are rife, and the image evokes pathos. But at the same time, we also need to be considerate to other users and not have such a graphic scene within a user profile. As Zoe noted, *The Guardian* is a separate website. They are free to show whatever imagery they see fit. I would assume they could go all the way and show you what said dead body looked like under the sheet if they wanted. [Similar reporting on the Ukraine does not go that far](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/russia-ukraine-war-mykolaiv-strike-boy-pulled-rubble-putin-revenge-rcna52154). We don't need to be that graphic on Stack Overflow.

To be as clear as possible

1. You don't need to change your views on the war. Your avatar, as-is, is just fine in that regard
2. You can definitely remind people of the terrible war going on over there
3. Please do not depict blood, violence or gruesome things in your profile. That image walked right up to that line, and it was removed since it is potentially disturbing to look at. You can make the exact same point you were aiming to make without that level of detail.

Comment: Re *"over there"*: Not for us. It is figuratively in our backyards.

Answer (score 12):

It's probably because the photo could be argued to evoke [a strong emotional trigger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/175248), depending on how much of the son was in the picture.

Note: the link I'm using is the general guideline that is applied when it comes to content in profiles.